# Completely removing Tensorflow, pip and virtualenv

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, virtualenv

I am new to all the tensorflow and Python programming and have installed tensorflow through pip and virtualenv but now I read that in order to use Spyder for Python it is best to use Anaconda. I know that tf can be installed through conda as well but how do I go about it now? Do I have to completely remove the existing installations first and if yes, can someone explain in detail which and how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just install Anaconda it will take care of everything. Uninstalling the existing ones is up to you, they wont harm anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after a short reading into the topic, I simply unistalled tf using sudo pip uninstall tensorflow within my virtualenv and then deactivated the virtualenv. Don't know how to really uninstall the virtualenv as well but I guess that is already enough then and I can proceed with the installation of Anaconda?

I also have installed some additional packages like mathplotlib, ipython etc. but I can keep them as well without problems?

Thanks